# Cannot Find the Syntax Error Near Process

Tags: vhdl

I'm very new to VHDL and this one must be a really easy question. The code gives me the error that there is a syntax error near the last process, please take a look:

library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

```
entity fsm is
    Port ( D : in STD_LOGIC_vector(1 downto 0);   
           CLK : in STD_LOGIC;
           outLed : out STD_LOGIC);
end fsm;

architecture Behavioral of fsm is
    type state_type is (s1,s2,s3,s4);
    signal next_state, state: state_type;
begin
    process(CLK)
    begin
        if rising_edge(CLK) then
        state <= next_state;
        end if;
    end process;
    outLed <= '1' when state = S1 and D = "01" else
              '1' when state = S2 and (D = "01" or D = "10") else
              '1' when state = S3 and (D="01" or D= "10") else
              '1' when state = S4 and D="10" else
              '0';
     process(state, clk) begin
        case state is
            when S1 =>
                if D= "01" then next_state <= S2;
                else next_state <= S1; end if;
            when S2 =>
                if D="10" then next_state <= S1;
                elsif D = "01" then next_state <= S3;
                else next_state <= S2; end if;
            when S3 =>
                if D = "10" then next_state <= S2;
                elsif D = "01" then next_state <= S4;
                else next_state <= S3; end if;
            when S4 =>
                if D = "10" then next_state <= S3;
                else next_State <= S4; end if;
            when others =>
                next_state <= S1;
      end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Thank you.

Comment: the process ends before the end of the case statement `end case;` Admittedly the compiler could give a clearer error message; others usually do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There needs to be an "end case" statement, before the "end process" statement. This is basic vhdl syntax. Despite writing a lot of VHDL over the years, I didn't know by looking at it. I just googled it.